# how can i change CSS to have two column showing two products instead of one?

Tags: css, wordpress

my woocommerce website has only one column that show only one product per column in mobile mode . i am trying to change it to show two products per column when is responsive.
how can i change CSS to have two column showing two products instead of one when is responsive mode?
i tried the code below that is copied from another website :

```css
@media(max-width:760px){
 .tab-content {
  width:50%;
  float:left; 
  }
  }
```

but i think that is not correct .

and i tried the code :

```css
@media(max-width:760px){
 .owl-item {
  width:50%;
  float:left; 
  }
  }
```

but non of them can't solve my problem .
url of my website is -> [URL](http://www.almahdionline.ir/)

Comment: The above css code is applied to your /shop page.

Comment: no . that is applied to my home page below of main slider.